# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModulesHelper::getActions()

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

When I create new module using Roksproket, I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModulesHelper::getActions() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pgocaribbeantv\administrator\components\com_roksprocket\views\module\view.html.php on line 139

What might the problem be?

Comment: Have you ensured you're using the latest version of RokSprocket and Joomla?

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Joomla 3.2.2, the getActions function was meant to be depreciated and then removed.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3061

For now you can try upgrading RockSprocket as they added a release to work around the bug (see their changelog):

http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/roksprocket